# Ubuntu_Remington_Hindi_Typing

Tags: unicode

Please Help
I've installed 20.04.4 LTS version
I've also installed ibus m17n
Facing difficulty on hindi typing
For Ex और I've to type Its look like आ then ao then र
For ex मार्ग it look मागर्
For ex विविधताओं I haven't type ओं

Comment: Hello. As written this is totally unreadable. Change the language back to English and clean up the question please.

Comment: Sir i am from India
Problem facing on Unicode (Remington) typing
Ibusm17n installed but Hex code Ctrl+Shift+U code not working

Comment: Please edit the question and add that info.